# How to add user profile picture in flutter using firebase auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i am using flutter authentication to register users through email and password and i am saving the email, phonenumber, username and image url.

How can i upload the image and store it in the "photourl" variable.

Is there a way of getting Imageurl after user has uploaded profile image using image picker??.

My Firebase authentication code is below.

```
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword({String email,password,username,image,phoneNumber}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password
      );

      User user = userCredential.user;
      assert(user.uid != null);
      email = user.email;
      username = user.displayName;
      image = user.photoURL;
      phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This question should be improved to be helpful for others. Here is a good resource on how to write a good question [ask] and the importance of a minimal reproducable example [repro]. Community members please use "flag"/"close" votes to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using imagePicker you get a File object. Now if you want u can use this File Object to display the image. Here though you would have to save the image file in a local directory.

```
File picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
Image.file(picture, width: 500, height: 500),// You can use this same file to display the image.
```

If However you want to convert the File to a url and save it to the User Object. Then all you need to do is save the file in a db(or s3 bucket), create a url and then save it to the user object. You can then use Image.network("url") to display it.

Comment: can I save `userCredential.user.photoURL` here? @Ayush

Answer (score 1):

You should check documentation on [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) or other storage options like AWS s3 etc... Also, maybe instead of trying to change this specific "photoURL", you can create a firestore database where you will have a document for each user.

Then, basically, pick an image, store it to a cdn/db, get the url to your image, insert it alongside other variables for your specific user.

You can check this video for the image picking/storing/retrieving:
[Flutter: Upload Files to Firebase Storage (Image, Video, PDF, etc.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3x92z0oHbtY)

userCredential.user.photoURL is the existing profile photo for users (via Google for example)